# Azure SDK 2.0 Upgrade button not available

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-sdk-.net

I installed the latest Azure SDK 2.0 on my development machine, but can't find the **"Upgrade"** button to upgrade my current project to the latest SDK. Googling how to upgrade show that previous upgrades had an "upgrade" button when going to the **Cloud Project -> Properties -> Application** Tab and the upgrade button will be next to the **Windows Azure Tools Version: October 2012.**

Why wouldn't I see the Upgrade button? If I want to manually upgrade my project, what would the process of doing so be?

The current version of the SDK used is SDK 1.8

Comment: I just tried it in VS 2012 (Premium edition) and I see an "Upgrade" button when going to the Cloud Project -> Properties -> Application Tab. What version of VS are you using? Also what's the .net version used by your cloud service projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when I opened the Web Platform Installer to install the latest SDK, the item that said "...SDK... - Latest" wasn't the latest, but the February 2013 (1.8.1) update instead of the 2.0 SDK. I ended up uninstalling all Azure SDK's, restarted the machine and tried again.

This solved the issue and I was presented with a new option to install the 2.0 SDK. The trick was to uninstall all (including any PowerShell cmd's) Azure related products I could find in Product and Features (Win 8).

Comment: Have you done anything else? I removed 1.9, reinstalled 2.0 SDK and restarted my machine, but still no luck. Did you also uninstall other Azure related products (e.g. Azure Storage Explorer, Azure Management Studio)?

Comment: I just removed all the Azure related components developed by Microsoft. Applications developed by other companies I left untouched.